# If Neo survived in the first movie, how come he didn't in the third movie?

Tags: the-matrix, the-matrix-revolutions

In the first *Matrix* movie Agent Smith and Neo survived the green explosion from inside the agent. But in the third movie Neo and Smith both died as a result of the same attack in the first movie. How did this happen?

Comment: In the first movie, Neo basically decompiles Smith's code from the inside and destroys him. In the third movie, Smith overwrites Neo's RSI, giving the machine city the opening they need to pump an antivirus into the Matrix and cleanse all of the Smith-infected code. How is that the same attack?

Comment: No I understand, I didn't though about it that way I was so confused. Your comment is the best answer. Thanx!

Comment: @Roger: You should really just convert your comment into an answer, as it has clearly satisfied the OP.

Comment: @AndrewMartin Since no one's come along with anything more substantial, I think I'll take your advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not the same attack.

In the first movie, Neo enters Smith's code and basically decompiles him from the inside, which presumably destroys him (though we know enough of him survives to resurface with "upgrades" taken from Neo).

In the third movie, Smith overwrites Neo's RSI, which, because Neo is hooked into the Matrix directly from the machine city at the time, gives the machine city the opening they need to pump an antivirus into the Matrix and cleanse all of the Smith-infected code. This purges the Smith code from the Matrix completely, but has the side effect of killing Neo.

Comment: What does RSI stand for here?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Residual Self Image. Basically it's like the character's in-Matrix avatar. [More information](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Residual_self_image)

Comment: @roger Which means anyone could have done the same job?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani I wouldn't go that far. If the machines could have used any Smith-infected person to pump the antivirus through, I'm certain they would have. My theory is that the irregularities in Neo's mind/code created a sort of superuser access that allowed the machines to bypass the normal code checks that the Smith virus would have corrupted and insert the antivirus directly into the Smith core process.