# What is the current status of Neo in the matrix?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-matrix-revolutions

I want to know what is the current status of NEO "The ONE" in The Matrix. Is he dead? Or is he alive? Or is he in some kind of Limbo state? Why couldn't he do some alternate method to defeat the machines.

Comment: See a related question [here](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/24965/if-neo-survived-in-the-first-movie-how-come-he-didnt-in-the-third-movie).

Comment: @Walt - Related? *Very related*. These two questions could be paternal twins.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed [in this question - If Neo survived in the first movie, how come he didn't in the third movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/24965/5603), Neo dies at the end of Matrix Revolutions, protecting Zion and ensuring the future of humanity.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is going to be [Matrix 4](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10838180/), it means Neo is not dead, at least not in any final way.

There is even a leaked image of Neo in his new life/form:

[image: Neo in Matrix 4]

([source](https://www.esquire.com/entertainment/movies/a28764367/keanu-reeves-matrix-4/))

Comment: from your link: "Though it's teased in the end that Neo will return, it's unclear how both Reeves and Moss will reprise their roles in a sequel." So not very conclusive yet.

Comment: @Luciano as I see it, he will be there for sure, just unclear how exactly.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of Matrix Revolutions, we see Sati asking the Oracle if they'll see Neo again.
The Oracle answers thinking so.

I think what Neo has become, transcends the definitions of life and death. Neo consciousness can probably appear active again in machine networks.